# Remote object fails only when backend COM dll accesses file

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, remoting

I've got a new .net 3.5 application that, via remoting, access objects from a legacy commerce system (.net 1.1). The old commerce system utilizes an even older COM dll that, among other things, generates and parses encrypted strings (product license keys).

We have several other systems (all .net 2.0) that access this same commerce back end. Those have been running successfully for over five years.

My new application works great. The remoting objects work perfectly. I can even use it to parse those encrypted key strings, which does use the dll. But, in just this one extremely narrow case it fails: generating those encrypted key strings.

When my app calls the remote object, the remote object calls the dll to generate the string. I can tell, via logging, that the string is generated and assigned to a property of the remote object. But on the front side, my .net 3.5 app fails. It gets the dreaded "Requested Service Not Found" error. And this *only* happens when I generate the key string. Everything else works.

Oh, and of course, it works fine in my development environment, but not on the production servers even though the older 2.0 apps work fine on the production servers.

The COM dll is a black box to me. The only thing I've been able to find out that is unique to the key generator method is that it accesses an ini file (to ensure key uniqueness).

So, what I'm left with is this: Is there some kind of change between .net 2.0 and 3.5 that introduced new rules about remote object and what they're allowed to do (like limiting file system access)?

Comment: One month. No love. I've resorted to contacting the original developer of the black box dll and asking for source code. *sigh*

Comment: Success, sort of. I explained the problem to the original developer. He dusted off his source code and created a new DLL for me that skipped the file I/O. Sure enough, it works. So, there is no question that something about the file I/O in the unmanaged dll caused my remote object to terminate too soon. I have no answer to the real question (Why?!), but at least my stuff works and I can close this project!!